André Gide and the classicist and romantic authors
André Gide in a short text compares classicism and romantism. In this passage, he speaks about their relation to emotion and speech. He asserts that classicists, in contrary to romantics, manage to master emotion.

The Romantic author always falls short of his words; we must always look beyond them for the classic author. A certain ability to pass too quickly, too easily, from emotion to speech is the hallmark of all French Romantics - hence their lack of effort to take possession of emotion other than through speech, their lack of effort to master it. The important thing for them is no longer to be moved, but to appear to be moved. In Greek literature, in Racine, in Pascal, in Baudelaire, we sense that the word, while revealing emotion, does not contain all of it, and that, once the word has been spoken, the emotion that preceded it continues. In Ronsard, Corneille and Hugo, to name but a few of the great names, emotion seems to end with the word and remain there; it is verbal and the verb exhausts it; the only resonance to be found is the resonance of the voice.

I am not very sure if the examples of Ronsard, Corneille and Hugo are supposed to illustrate the French romantics, while the examples of the Greeks, Racine, Pascal and Baudelaire are supposed to illustrate the classicists. Baudelaire was not a classicist, he was very closed to the romantics. Hugo was considered a romantic. Pascal is to me more seen as a moralist. Etc.
How is Gide defining "romanticism" and "classicism", and what does he mean by all this?
References:
Gide, Incidences, 1924, Essais, Critiques, Pléiade p.281

What exactly is your question? You seem to be saying, "I disagree with Gide" and that's it.

Ronsard was 16th century; Corneille was 17th century; Hugo was 19th century. Hugo is the only one of these who is commonly called a Romantic. And Baudelaire was post-Hugo (born 20 years later), while the classicists are supposed to be before the romantics.

@PeterShor I don't think Gide is using "classicist" and "romantic" purely as period concepts. (By the way, Barbey d'Aurevilly described Baudelaire as "tourné vers le classicisme, nourri de romantisme".)

@Tsudoku: So maybe the proper question (which the OP did not explicitly ask) is: "How is Gide defining 'romanticism' and 'classicism', and what does he mean by all this?"

@PeterShor Yes. Thanks. I corrected.

There are a few issues with the translation: , l'on sent
que la parole [we sense that speech while revealing emotions [rather than emotion, sing. like in the French] does not contain all of them and once words are spoken the emotion preceding them continues on.
